# What is the Dart equivalent of Java byte[]

Tags: dart, flutter

I am experimenting with Flutter and need to make a plugin package for Android and iOS, and have started with Android. The Android Java code I need to communicate with uses a byte array (byte[]) both as input and as return type for some of its methods. What does this map to in Dart?

Comment: Either just `List<int>` or https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html (`Uint8List`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dart has a `dart:typed_data` core library exactly for this purpose:

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html

I'm not 100% sure of how this maps to the Flutter plugin model, though I suspect a Flutter user or developer can fill us in :)

Answer (score 25):

Here is the standard type mapping for platform channels:

https://flutter.io/platform-channels/#codec

On Android, `byte[]` maps to [`Uint8List`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `List<int>` like so:

```dart
List<int> data = [102, 111, 114, 116, 121, 45, 116, 119, 111, 0];
```

Or `Uint8List` like this:

```dart
// import 'dart:typed_data';

Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList([102, 111, 114, 116, 121, 45, 116, 119, 111, 0]);
```

Also check out `ByteBuilder`, `ByteData`, and `ByteBuffer` for more byte manipulation options. Read [Working with bytes in Dart](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-bytes-in-dart-6ece83455721) for more info.